# Pater Noster Rig

Tags: fishing

Could you please provide information regarding the tools (hook, swivels, hooks, main line, line for hooks, floaters, stoppers etc) and right distances & dimensions among each tool needed to create a Pater Noster rig suitable for Sargo & Bass?